# Hide ngx-bootstrap tooltip when clicking outside after opening it with delay

Tags: angular, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

I need to display a [tooltip from ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/3.0.1/#/tooltip) after hold-clicking a div for a moment (let's say half a second). After that, the tooltip should close when clicking outside of it. I've been trying with:

```
triggers="mousedown:click" [delay]="500"
triggers="mousedown:focusout" [delay]="500"
triggers="mousedown:blur" [delay]="500"
```

But none of them seem to work. "focusout" and "blur" don't seem to work at all, and the problem with "click" is that is fired when the mouse button is released after the "mousedown", hiding the tooltip.

Comment: Hi! Do you have to explicitly click outside to close it afterwards or do you mean just releasing outside afterwards should close the tooltip?

Comment: @Lucho Hi, I need to click outside of it to close it.

Comment: posted an example of a way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

First off, the API doesn't support "longpress" as that's out of scope of the framework (IMO). So two things:

- "Long-press" you can do in several ways, one way (without importing libs) is by making use of the [@Hostlistener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) and [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) API and listen to the events and use ngx-bootstrap [manual triggering](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#triggers-manual) on when to show or hide the tooltip like so:

**component.ts**

```
public progress: boolean = false;
protected interval: any;

@ViewChild('pop', { static: false }) public tooltip: TooltipDirective ;

@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
  this.startInterval()
}

@HostListener('mouseup', ['$event']) onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
  this.stopInterval();
}

private startInterval() {
  this.interval = setInterval(()=> {
    this.tooltip.show()
  }, 1500);
}

private stopInterval(): void {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<p>
  <span tooltip="Hello there! I was triggered manually"
    triggers="focus" #pop="bs-tooltip">
  </span>
</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Tooltip with 1.5sec delay
</button>
```

- "Outside click" works with regular tooltip attributes `trigger="focus"` tooltip config, however it does not work with manual trigger it seems so you can simply fall back on Angular API with @Hostlistener and by adding a isLongPressed boolean to read when tooltip is manually triggered or not like so:

**Parent component.ts:**

```
@ViewChild('button', { static: false}) private button: DelayButtonComponent;

@HostListener ('mouseup',['$event']) onPressUp(event: MouseEvent) {
  if(this.button.isLongPress) {
    this.button.isLongPress = !this.button.isLongPress;
  } else {
    this.button.isLongPress = !this.button.isLongPress;
    this.button.tooltip.hide();
  }
}
```

Here's the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-tooltip-longpress-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) in action

Comment: Thanks! I still cound't test this so I can't confirm if it's working for my case, but I'll let you know as soon as I can and accept the answer. Looks promising so far!